# Take sum of a concatenated column SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, greenplum

I want to use post and pre revenue of an interaction to calculate net revenue. Sometimes there are multiple customers in an interaction. The data is like:

```
InteractionID | Customer ID |   Pre  |  Post
--------------+-------------+--------+--------
      1       | ab12        |   10   |  30
      2       | cd12        |   40   |  15
      3       | de12;gh12   | 15;30  | 20;10
```

Expected output is to take sum in pre and post call to calculate net

```
    InteractionID | Customer ID   |   Pre  |  Post | Net 
    --------------+---------------+--------+-------+------
          1       |  ab12         |   10   |  30   | 20
          2       |  cd12         |   40   |  15   | -25
          3       |  de12;gh12    |   45   |  30   | -15
```

How do I get the net revenue column?

Comment: So you want (20+10) - (15+30) as your Net if there are more than 1 customer right?

Comment: @Arun
Yes the above is correct.
There can be more than 2 customers as well. The number of customers should be dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper solution is to normalize your relational design by adding a separate table for customers and their respective `pre` and `post`.

While stuck with the current design, this would do it:

```sql
SELECT *, post - pre AS net
FROM (
   SELECT interaction_id, customer_id 
         ,(SELECT sum(x::numeric) FROM string_to_table(pre, ';') x) AS pre
         ,(SELECT sum(x::numeric) FROM string_to_table(post, ';') x) AS post
   FROM   tbl
   ) sub;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6a5a3cf3d8a954a6645daf0587dd1917)*

[`string_to_table()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) requires at least Postgres 14.
You did not declare your Postgres version, so I assume the current version Postgres 14.

For older versions replace with `regexp_split_to_table()` or `unnest(string_to array))`.